# In controller A, open contained controller B through UIButton

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue

How do I hook up a UIButton that is inside controller A, so that it opens a controller B that is contained inside controller A (inside a "Container View") using storyboards?

Ie controller B only takes up part of controller A area. Controller A would still be partly visible.

Background:
When adding a controller B to a Container View inside another controller A, it defaults to opening the controller B as soon as controller A loads. I want controller B to be hidden first, then have it open by the tap of a button.

Comment: Don't suppose you have an image to show what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Taking apart the view lifecycle for nib/storyboard launched resources will help here.

You need to hide the view of Controller B sometime after it has been created and loaded, but before it has been displayed. Then in response to an action, you need to unhide the view (or do some fancier presentation).

Typically you will declare a property within Controller A of:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ControllerB *controllerB;
```

Which you wire up in the storyboard.
Now you have a reference to to your controllerB instance which you can make use of from within controllerA's code.

Since you've nested controllerB's view inside of the view hierarchy of controllerA in the storyboard, your instance of controllerB will exist and be ready to manipulate as soon as -viewDidLoad is called on controllerA.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_controllerB.view setHidden:YES];
    //other setup and configuration of controllerA
}
```

You could do this at viewWillAppear, or a few other places, but as long as you hide controllerB.view before -viewDidAppear is called, you'll be fine.

Then you have controllerA respond to the button push something like this:

```
- (IBAction)userPressedTheButton:(id)sender
{
    [_controllerB.view setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easy stuff. You could create an outlet for the container view

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
```

In `viewDidLoad` just hide it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.containerView.hidden = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

Unhide it on button click